# Change default browser by project or solution in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, browser

i have to work on various web projects for different customers. some use IE only, some Firefox and other browsers in their companys.

i would like to debug project/solution A with IE and project/solution B with firefox (and so on) by just hitting F5 or "view in browser".

I do **NOT** want to switch the default browser in visual studio via:

- right click on an .aspx file in the solution explorer
- browse with...
- selecting the browser i want to use
- pressing "set as default" to make it remember my choise (optional)

everytime i have to work on another project/solution.

Can i save the default browser by solution or project and NOT via VS global settings somehow?

do you have any hint for me how to archive this? is there maybe even an addin for this?

thanks, toebens

Answer (score 2):

In the project properties, in the Web section you can have it start an external application with parameters at the start of debug (F5) so you could specify the path of the browser as the Start External program path and the http://servername:port/virtualdirectory as the command line argument

[alt text http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/3708/projectprops.gif](http://img142.imageshack.us/img142/3708/projectprops.gif)

Comment: this would be an option altough it only starts on the specific application root you set in "command line arguments".
is it possible that IE will get the current project and the current page i selected to start with?